# how can substrate prometheus metrics be used to monitor and alert on the number of concurrent connections?

Tags: monitoring, metrics, prometheus

i'd like to monitor the number of connections each node is handling on its ws, rpc and p2p ports with a view to right-sizing infrastructure capacity to exceed the typical load by a learned safe margin.

has anyone figured out what the prometheus rules might look like?

i've identified these metrics that i believe contain the right information:

```yaml
# HELP substrate_rpc_requests_finished Number of RPC requests (not calls) processed by the server.
# TYPE substrate_rpc_requests_finished counter
- substrate_rpc_requests_finished{protocol="http",chain="calamari"} 1580264
- substrate_rpc_requests_finished{protocol="ws",chain="calamari"} 167445457

# HELP substrate_rpc_requests_started Number of RPC requests (not calls) received by the server.
# TYPE substrate_rpc_requests_started counter
- substrate_rpc_requests_started{protocol="http",chain="calamari"} 1580264
- substrate_rpc_requests_started{protocol="ws",chain="calamari"} 167445473

# HELP substrate_rpc_sessions_closed Number of persistent RPC sessions closed
# TYPE substrate_rpc_sessions_closed counter
- substrate_rpc_sessions_closed{chain="calamari"} 1104752

# HELP substrate_rpc_sessions_opened Number of persistent RPC sessions opened
# TYPE substrate_rpc_sessions_opened counter
- substrate_rpc_sessions_opened{chain="calamari"} 1104821

# HELP substrate_sub_libp2p_connections_closed_total Total number of connections closed, by direction and reason
# TYPE substrate_sub_libp2p_connections_closed_total counter
- substrate_sub_libp2p_connections_closed_total{direction="out",reason="keep-alive-timeout",chain="calamari"} 5154
- substrate_sub_libp2p_connections_closed_total{direction="out",reason="ping-timeout",chain="calamari"} 55
- substrate_sub_libp2p_connections_closed_total{direction="out",reason="transport-error",chain="calamari"} 11846

# HELP substrate_sub_libp2p_connections_opened_total Total number of connections opened by direction
# TYPE substrate_sub_libp2p_connections_opened_total counter
- substrate_sub_libp2p_connections_opened_total{direction="out",chain="calamari"} 17093

# HELP substrate_sub_libp2p_distinct_peers_connections_closed_total Total number of connections closed with distinct peers
# TYPE substrate_sub_libp2p_distinct_peers_connections_closed_total counter
- substrate_sub_libp2p_distinct_peers_connections_closed_total{chain="calamari"} 17055

# HELP substrate_sub_libp2p_distinct_peers_connections_opened_total Total number of connections opened with distinct peers
# TYPE substrate_sub_libp2p_distinct_peers_connections_opened_total counter
- substrate_sub_libp2p_distinct_peers_connections_opened_total{chain="calamari"} 17093

# HELP substrate_sub_libp2p_incoming_connections_total Total number of incoming connections on the listening sockets
# TYPE substrate_sub_libp2p_incoming_connections_total counter
- substrate_sub_libp2p_incoming_connections_total{chain="calamari"} 0
```

my statistics and promql foo falls something short of ninja and i don't really understand how to write the expression i need. take the following promql queries, for example:

- [substrate rpc requests finished](https://pulse.pelagos.systems/graph?g0.expr=substrate_rpc_requests_finished%7Bprotocol%3D%22ws%22%7D%5B1m%5D&g0.tab=1&g0.stacked=0&g0.show_exemplars=0&g0.range_input=1h&g0.end_input=2022-04-18%2018%3A03%3A35&g0.moment_input=2022-04-18%2018%3A03%3A35)

  ```
  substrate_rpc_requests_finished{protocol="ws"}[1m]
  ```

  [image: substrate rpc requests finished]
- [rate of substrate rpc requests finished](https://pulse.pelagos.systems/graph?g0.expr=rate(substrate_rpc_requests_finished%7Bprotocol%3D%22ws%22%7D%5B1m%5D)&g0.tab=0&g0.stacked=0&g0.show_exemplars=0&g0.range_input=1h&g0.end_input=2022-04-18%2018%3A03%3A35&g0.moment_input=2022-04-18%2018%3A03%3A35)

  ```
  rate(substrate_rpc_requests_finished{protocol="ws"}[1m])
  ```

  [image: rate of: substrate rpc requests finished]

it's not apparent to me what these queries are telling me. i think `substrate_rpc_requests_finished{protocol="ws"}[1m]` is telling me that some nodes are handling more than 100 million ws requests per minute. these numbers surprise me. have i misinterpreted them? i don't understand what wrapping the query in `rate()` does. the [docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#rate) suggest it's the request increase rate over the previous period. if so, it's not what i need as i'm interested in *volume* rather than *increase*.

### what i really want to know is:

- what query expression would tell me that a node is approaching `--ws-max-connections` (see also: [what's a good value for `--ws-max-connections`?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/889/whats-a-good-value-for-ws-max-connections))?
- what other query expressions could tell me about rpc (http) and p2p connection volumes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i did not find a good metric exposed by substrate-node with which ws connections can be monitored.
i did find that [prometheus node-exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter) provides a *good enough* metric in `node_netstat_Tcp_CurrEstab` which monitors the total number of *established* tcp connections being handled by the node host/instance. while this metric includes more than just the ws connections, in practice, the resolution is good enough to provide the information required on a host dedicated to running a single substrate node, since ws accounts for pretty much all of the tcp connections beyond the first 100 or so.

node-exporter can be installed like so:

```bash
version=1.3.1

# download
curl -L \
  -o /tmp/node_exporter-${version}.linux-amd64.tar.gz \
  https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter/releases/download/v${version}/node_exporter-${version}.linux-amd64.tar.gz

# extract
sudo tar xvfz \
  /tmp/node_exporter-${version}.linux-amd64.tar.gz \
  -C /usr/local/bin \
  --strip-components=1 \
  node_exporter-${version}.linux-amd64/node_exporter

# clean up
rm /tmp/node_exporter-${version}.linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

it can be run as a systemd service by creating a unit file at

`/etc/systemd/system/prometheus-node-exporter.service`:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=prometheus node exporter
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/node_exporter
Restart=always
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and then enabled and started with:

```bash
sudo systemctl enable --now prometheus-node-exporter.service
```

when its metrics url is added to prometheus server configuration, the tcp metrics can be [visualised](https://pulse.pelagos.systems/graph?g0.expr=node_netstat_Tcp_CurrEstab%7Bjob%3D%7E%22.*dolphin.*%22%7D&g0.tab=0&g0.stacked=0&g0.show_exemplars=0&g0.range_input=1d), monitored and alerted on.
[image: tcp connections]

Answer (score 2):

The rate function is actually what you need, increase is required in the context of a time serie db like Prometheus with a metric only increasing.

What makes you think your nodes are handling million or requests per second? The scale I see on your graph is 0-25 which makes sense.

Here is an example of this query `rate(substrate_rpc_requests_started{job="astar-public-node"}[$__rate_interval])`:
[image]

You can consider stacking series to have an overall usage of the network:
[image]

EDIT: `rate` will only give you average number of requests per second.
For a different time scale to estimate whole load, better use `increase` instead:

```
increase(substrate_rpc_requests_started{}[1m])
```

[image]

For open connections, this makes it easily:

```
substrate_rpc_sessions_opened{}-substrate_rpc_sessions_closed{}
```